# How to remove list it (li) element from a list in IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to remove an `li` element from a `ul` list.
i'm using old fashion java script with chrome and IE 9/10.

the java script code is pretty straight forward

```
document.getElementById(someid).remove();
```

This works perfectly in chrome but IE (version 10.0.92) gives me the following error

```
"Object doesn't support property or method 'Remove'"
```

How can I dynamically remove the an `li` element from the list ?

Comment: The method in IE is [`removeNode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than [`remove()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536694%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `removeChild()` on the `parentElement`. For example:

```
document.getElementById(someid).parentElement.removeChild(document.getElementById(someid));
```

Alternatively, you can use JavaScript's prototyping to add a `remove()` function:

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() 
{
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
```

This can then easily be called using your initial code:

```
document.getElementById(someid).remove();
```

Comment: At least add a check before trying to add it to the prototype of a native object to make it future proof.